# remove all words that start with "@" from a string

Tags: r

how can I remove all words that start with "@" from a string?

For example, 
"@AgnezMo On @AirAsia Airbus A320-216 Fleet with @NinetologyMY Livery -- 9M-AHG cc: @AgnesMonicaEnt @agnezone http://t.co/hfXwUQq2Oq"

I would like to have the string to be
"On Airbus A320-216 Fleet with Livery -- 9M-AHG cc: http://t.co/hfXwUQq2Oq"

Comment: Hi, Thanks! One more question, I notice that when using gsub it is case sensitive. Is that possible to remove "AgnezMo" from the data regardless of uppercase or lowercase? In other words, I would like to remove AGNEZMO, agnezmo, agNEZMO etc (in whatever possible combinations of upper/lower case)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this where `s` is the input:

```
gsub("@\\w+ *", "", s)
```

giving:

```
"On Airbus A320-216 Fleet with Livery -- 9M-AHG cc: http://t.co/hfXwUQq2Oq"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! One more question, I notice that when using gsub it is case sensitive. Is that possible to remove "AgnezMo" from the data regardless of uppercase or lowercase? In other words, I would like to remove AGNEZMO, agnezmo, agNEZMO etc (in whatever possible combinations of upper/lower case)

Comment: \w matches either case.

Comment: Hey, this help me too. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex with R via the `sub` call, as described [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html).

The regular expression to match those would be: `@\w+\s+`.

Comment: Adi, not sure what you edited here? You just changed "regular expression" to "regex"?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do like this :

```
xx <-  "@AgnezMo On @AirAsia Airbus A320-216 Fleet with @NinetologyMY Livery -- 9M-AHG cc: @AgnesMonicaEnt @agnezone http://t.co/hfXwUQq2Oq"
gsub("@([a-zA-Z0-9]|[_])*", "", xx)

## [1] " On  Airbus A320-216 Fleet with  Livery -- 9M-AHG cc:   http://t.co/hfXwUQq2Oq"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `str` is the string,

```
> gsub("@[A-Za-z]+ ", "", str)
# [1] "On Airbus A320-216 Fleet with Livery -- 9M-AHG cc: http://t.co/hfXwUQq2Oq"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use character classes with the str_replace_all function from the stringr package:

```
usercomment <- c("@AgnezMo On @AirAsia Airbus A320-216 Fleet with @NinetologyMY Livery -- 9M-AHG cc: @AgnesMonicaEnt @agnezone")

library(stringr)
test <- str_replace_all(usercomment,"[:punct:]","")
test
```

You can also string together different character classes using the or operator, so you can replace characters and space with one line. Look at this code below to modify the column names of a dataframe to clean it up:

```
> colnames(order_table) <- str_replace_all(colnames(order_table),"[:punct:]|[:space:]","")
```